# while adding string(object) to the array giving unformatted string printing in nslog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to read `Ò ÉÑÎÔÜ  Ê` characters from XML and want to store it in an array. While reading strings from XML it is working showing fine and they are the same as the XML characters.

Now I inserted them into a mutable array. When I am trying to print that array, it gives strange values: instead of `ÒÙ ÉÑÎÔÜ  Ê` it shows `"\U00dc","\U00ca\U00db\U00ce\U00cd", "\U00d7",(the array values)`.

Can anyone gives me some suggestion why it is happening?

I am using `[textWord addObject:currentElement];` to insert objects to the array. Here `currentElement` is an `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are the unicode character for you special character, whats the problem with that.

Comment: i am inserting ÒÙ string i need same string again some where in the program.

Comment: there is no problem in this when you get string from array again it will convert it into origional string.

Comment: i printed in a log statement after inserting all objects it is showing as \U00dc instead of Ò.now it is clearly showing wrongly then wer it can show exactly.

Comment: i also add a string "ÉÑÎÔÜ" to a NSMutableArray and get it again in a seperate NSString then print new string in log it's giving me the same string as i inserted "ÉÑÎÔÜ"